# Infinite scroll make page number auto increase after first scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am working in infinite load, when i am first scroll to the bottom, the next data load to page. But after the next data load to page, it makes another data to be load and it load when I'm not continue to scroll again.

for example, when i first scroll to bottom the URL change to tes.html?page=1, but after a few seconds it will change to tes.html?page=2, tes.html?page=3 and so on. How to make page number change in URL and load data based on page number when scroll again?

Heres' the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  let articleText = document.querySelector(".article_ct .text");
  let currentPage = 1;
  let totalPage = 5;

  function loadData(currentPage) {
    fetch("index.json")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
        let text = document.createElement("p");
        text.style.marginBottom = "100px";
        text.innerText = result[currentPage].text;
        articleText.append(text);
        history.pushState(null, null, `tes.html?page=${currentPage}`);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    return true;
  }

  // LOAD DATA PERTAMA

  fetch("index.json")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => {
      let text = document.createElement("p");
      text.style.marginBottom = "100px";
      text.innerText = result[0].text;
      articleText.append(text);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));

  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if (
      $(this).scrollTop() >
      articleText.offsetHeight + articleText.offsetTop + 100
    ) {
      if (currentPage <= totalPage) {
        $(".loader").css("display", "block");
        loadData(currentPage);
        currentPage++;
      } else {
        $(".loader").css("display", "none");
      }
    }
    // if($(this).scrollTop() > (articleText.offsetTop + articleText.offsetHeight)) {
    //   console.log('tes')
    // }
  });
});
```

Heres the json data file

```
[
    {
        "text": "The box sat on the desk next to the computer. It had arrived earlier in the day and business had interrupted her opening it earlier. She didn't who had sent it and briefly wondered who it might have been. As she began to unwrap it, she had no idea that opening it would completely change her life. If you can imagine a furry humanoid seven feet tall, with the face of an intelligent gorilla and the braincase of a man, you'll have a rough idea of what they looked like -- except for their teeth. The canines would have fitted better in the face of a tiger, and showed at the corners of their wide, thin-lipped mouths, giving them an expression of ferocity. There were only two ways to get out of this mess if they all worked together. The problem was that neither was all that appealing. One would likely cause everyone a huge amount of physical pain while the other would likely end up with everyone in jail. In Sam's mind, there was only one thing to do. He threw everyone else under the bus and he secretly sprinted away leaving the others to take the fall without him."
    },
    {
        "text": "April seriously wondered about her sleeping partner choices. She looked at her bed and what a mess it had become. How did she get to the point in her life where she had two dogs, three cats, and a raccoon sleeping with her every night? She patiently waited for his number to be called. She had no desire to be there, but her mom had insisted that she go. She's resisted at first, but over time she realized it was simply easier to appease her and go. Mom tended to be that way. She would keep insisting until you wore down and did what she wanted. So, here she sat, patiently waiting for her number to be called. Stranded. Yes, she was now the first person ever to land on Venus, but that was of little consequence. Her name would be read by millions in school as the first to land here, but that celebrity would never actually be seen by her. She looked at the control panel and knew there was nothing that would ever get it back into working order. She was the first and it was not clear th   is would also be her last."
    },
    {
        "text": "Should he write it down? That was the question running through his mind. He couldn't believe what had just happened and he knew nobody else would believe him as well. Even if he documented what had happened by writing it down, he still didn't believe anyone would still believe it. So the question remained. Was it be worth it to actually write it down? I inadvertently went to See's Candy last week (I was in the mall looking for phone repair), and as it turns out, See's Candy now charges a dollar -- a full dollar -- for even the simplest of their wee confection offerings. I bought two chocolate lollipops and two chocolate-caramel-almond things. The total cost was four-something. I mean, the candies were tasty and all, but let's be real: A Snickers bar is fifty cents. After this dollar-per-candy revelation, I may not find myself wandering dreamily back into a See's Candy any time soon."
    },
    {
        "text": "It was a scrape that he hardly noticed. Sure, there was a bit of blood but it was minor compared to most of the other cuts and bruises he acquired on his adventures. There was no way he could know that the rock that produced the cut had alien genetic material on it that was now racing through his bloodstream. He felt perfectly normal and continued his adventure with no knowledge of what was about to happen to him. He sat across from her trying to imagine it was the first time. It wasn't. Had it been a hundred? It quite possibly could have been. Two hundred? Probably not. His mind wandered until he caught himself and again tried to imagine it was the first time. Benny was tired. Not the normal every day tired from a hard day o work. The exhausted type of tired where you're surprised your body can even move. All he wanted to do was sit in front of the TV, put his feet up on the coffee table, and drink a beer. The only issue was that he had forgotten where he lived."
    },
    {
        "text": "It was a simple tip of the hat. Grace didn't think that anyone else besides her had even noticed it. It wasn't anything that the average person would notice, let alone remember at the end of the day. That's why it seemed so unbelievable that this little gesture would ultimately change the course of the world. She was aware that things could go wrong. In fact, she had trained her entire life in anticipation that things would go wrong one day. She had quiet confidence as she started to see that this was the day that all her training would be worthwhile and useful. At this point, she had no idea just how wrong everything would go that day. I checked in for the night at Out O The Way motel. What a bad choice that was. First I took a shower and a spider crawled out of the drain. Next, the towel rack fell down when I reached for the one small bath towel. This allowed the towel to fall halfway into the toilet. I tried to watch a movie, but the remote control was sticky and wouldn’t stop scrolling through the channels. I gave up for the night and crawled into bed. I stretched out my leg and felt something furry by my foot. Filled with fear, I reached down and to my surprise, I pulled out a raccoon skin pair of underwear. After my initial relief that it wasn’t alive, the image of a fat, ugly businessman wearing raccoon skin briefs filled my brain. I jumped out of the bed, threw my t"
    }
]
```